# how to optimize non-equality join in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables, one is `a`(1000 rows), another is `b`(70 million rows).

there is two field `starttime`,`endtime` in table `a` and one field `time` in table `b`.

I use **mapjoin** to query:

```
select /*+ MAPJOIN(a) */ a.starttime,a.endtime, b.time 
from a join b 
where b.time between a.starttime and a.endtime;
```

but execute very very slowly. mapreduce job always stay on 0%.

do you have another way to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

One method is just to expand `a` to have one row for every day.

Another method is to use an interleaving technique.  This assumes that `a` really partitions time, so there are no overlaps or gaps.  And, that `b` has a primary key.

So, for each `id` in `b` you can get the corresponding start time in `a`:

```
select id, time, max(starttime) over (order by time, priority) as a_starttime
from ((select b.id, b.time, null as starttime, 2j as priority from b) union all
      (select null, a.starttime, a.starttime, 1 as priority from a)
     ) ab;
```

Then you can use this with an equijoin:

```
select id, time, a.starttime, a.endtime
from (select id, time, max(starttime) over (order by time, priority) as a_starttime
      from ((select b.id, b.time, null as starttime, 2j as priority from b) union all
            (select null, a.starttime, a.starttime, 1 as priority from a)
           ) ab
     ) ab join
     a
     on ab.a_starttime = a.starttime;
```

Note:  This technique has worked well on other databases.  I have not had the opportunity to try it on Hive.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! In fact, there is many field in two table, using interleaving technique looks like troublesome and inconvenient, is it right? is there another way for this case?